# Come out of terminal output in Neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal

In nvim how can I come out of the terminal mode without closing the nvim overall?!

In Vim I just do `:!python script.py`, when I'm done reading the output I can hit enter to come out of the python shell.

In nvim I do now `:terminal python script.py`, I am directed to the python shell output, and there is no way to get back to my script. `:q` of course closes nvim.

This is feeling horrible in comparison how easy it was done in Vim!

Comment: Does NeoVim's `:terminal` replace the buffer in the current window? That's a bit odd, to me, since Vim's `:terminal` splits the window first. So C-w c or similar only closes the new window.

Answer (score 1):

To switch back to your script you can do: `:b#`

More information about the `:b` command with `:help :buffer`.
The `#` stand for the previously edited buffer.
You can list all the buffers and get their name and shortcut with the  `:ls` command.

If your stuck into the terminal mode (which I undestood you are not) you should type: <kbd>Ctrl-/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd>

To make it more easy you can introduce a terminal mapping into your `.vimrc` file..
e.g. to <kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd>:

```
tnoremap <C-q> <C-/><C-n>
```

Comment: And could you please tell me where I can read about the `:b#`, I didn't find anything listed under `:help :terminal`.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-. Thanks for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly. If the solution solves your problem you could validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons ;-)